# Find greater than X from list when X doesn't exist in list

Tags: java, list, binary-search

I am trying to find values from a list that are greater than certain value (known in my case).

Example:

Given

```
list = [1, 2, 5, 10, 15];  //list is sorted
```

Find values greater than `X` (`=7` in this case).

Desired result = Return a list with values = `[10, 15]`

I tried using java binary search, like

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, X);
```

My plan was to find index (of `X`) and then return all the elements after index.

But index return negative, that I understand because `7` is not in the list.

Is there any other way ? Someone please suggest.

Comment: Other way: create a new list and add the elements to it from the original list that are greater than X.

Answer (score 7):

If your list is sorted than [Collection#binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29) will return the index of the search key, if it is contained in the list; otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). You can calculate begin index of insertion_point like below:

```
     index= -(insertion_point) - 1
     -(insertion_point)= index+1
     insertion_point=-(index+1)
```

After got the begin index of `List` than you can apply [subList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) method to got the resulted list greater than X.

```
    Integer[] values = {1, 2, 5, 10, 15};
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(values));
    int X = 7;
    int index = Collections.binarySearch(list, X);

    int insertion_point = -(index+1); // As calculated above.

    List<Integer> res = list.subList(insertion_point, list.size());
    System.out.println(res);
```

**Output**: [10, 15]

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 8, you can use streams.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class So1 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 5, 10, 15);
        List result = list.stream().filter(s -> s > 7).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

For those kind of data computations, I seriously recommand looking into Clojure, which compiles to Java.

For example, this is how you would write it:

```
(filter
    #(> % 7) 
    [1 2 5 10 15])
```

Comment: The guy gave a question how to do it in java, not in clojure. Maybe he needs it for work where he can not go to his boss and ask for permission to start writing in Clojure.

Answer (score 1):

See [`Collections.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29):

> **Returns:**
>
> the index of the search key, if it is contained in the list; otherwise, `(-(insertion point)` - 1). The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the list: the index of the first element greater than the key, or `list.size()` if all elements in the list are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.

The method still returns something meaningful even if the element is not in the list, and this is exactly what you want. If the return value `r` is negative, then the insertion point is `-(r + 1)`. Of course, if `r` is positive, then the element *is* contained in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> list;
List<Intger> out;

int v = 7;
for int i : list
    if i > v
        out.add(i)
```

The brute force method if this is a small list will work.

you can use some of the methods available to List as well, such as subList -> [List API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

```
for int i; i < list.size() ; i++
    if list.get(i) > 7
         return list.subList(i,list.size())
return new List<Integer>() // return empty list
```

Answer (score 0):

A round about way of doing it could be to implement your own binary search algorithm using the traditional upper, lower and midpoint references. Usually when lower ends up being greater the upper in the below method it means the number your looking for is not in list however in you case you could use it as a reference to the index value for the remaining items in your list.

```
public int find(int searchKey){
    int lowerBound = 0;
    int upperBound = nElems-1;
    int check;

    while(true){
       check = (lowerBound + upperBound ) / 2;
       if(myArray[check]==searchKey){
           return check; // found it
        }else if(lowerBound > upperBound){
              //lowerbound is now the first index of the remaining values in the list.
              // I think. You might want to test it...

        }else{ // divide range
              if(myArray[check] < searchKey){
                 lowerBound = check + 1; // it's in upper half
              }else{
                   upperBound = check - 1; // it's in lower half
           }
        } // end else divide range
      } // end while
   } //
```