# Find smaller or equal to X from duplicated sorted list

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Given an array list and sorted

```
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(1);
list1.add(4);
list1.add(15);
list1.add(16);
list1.add(3);
list1.add(3);
list1.add(8);
System.out.println(list1); // [1, 4, 15, 16, 3, 3, 8]
Collections.sort(list1,3);
System.out.println(list1); // [1, 3, 3, 4, 8, 15, 16]
```

[To find larger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579652/find-greater-than-x-from-list-when-x-doesnt-exist-in-list) or equal in the sorted duplicated list, say '3'

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(list1, 3);
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<> (list1.subList(index < 0 ? - index - 1 : index, list1.size()));
```

which give us

```
[3,3,4,8,15,16]
```

But how to do that for smaller or equal case? Here is what I tried.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<> (list1.subList(0, index < 0 ? - index - 1 : index + 1));
```

which output

```
[1, 3]
```

expected output

```
[1, 3, 3]
```

Comment: You mean you want to find all duplicates that are bigger than a certain number  ? (3 in your example)

Comment: @OferYuval, my bad, it should be smaller or equal to 3.

Comment: Can you do the sort and find duplicates when adding numbers to the list ? Or do you need the list after all numbers were added to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` methods of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html. An example

```
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(4);
    list1.add(15);
    list1.add(16);
    list1.add(3);
    list1.add(3);
    list1.add(8);

    System.out.println(list1); // [1, 4, 15, 16, 3, 3, 8]
    Collections.sort(list1);
    System.out.println(list1); // [1, 3, 3, 4, 8, 15, 16]

    //For equals or larger than 3
    int index = list1.indexOf(3);
    List<Integer> list2 = index > -1 ? list1.subList(index, list1.size()) : new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(list2); // [3, 3, 4, 8, 15, 16]

    //For equals or smaller than 3
    index = list1.lastIndexOf(3);
    List<Integer> list3 = index > -1 ? list1.subList(0, index + 1) : new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(list3); // [1, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Another suggestion is by using shorthand method: 
`ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<> (list1.subList(0, index < 0 ? - index - 1 : list1.lastIndexOf(list1.get(index)) + 1));`.
However, this answer is not readable.

Comment: Updated the answer with check for missing the intended X in the list.